# Silly Visual Studio Pending Changes Question

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

I recently switched from a Java based project to a C#/.net project. I previously used IntelliJ which had the concept of change lists where you could group your pending changes together and check each group in individually.

I have two problems with the pending changes window in visual studio.

1) Every time I check anything in, visual studio checks the checkbox beside *Every* pending change in the list forcing me to uncheck each and every one of them so I don't accidentally check something in. This is extremely frustrating because there are several files that I need to keep changed to correctly run my code locally. Is there any way to change this default behavior to not check any pending changes on check-in?

2) Is there any way to group changes into lists as opposed one big bucket of changes? Again this becomes frustrating when I need to check something in, but I have to search through the files and check the pertinent changes. I understand that shelve sets exist using TFS, but that doesn't cut it for me, especially since I have several changed files that I need to keep altered in order to correctly deploy locally, and I rarely ever want to check in.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What SCCM are you using? And what SCCM client are you using?

Comment: I'm using Team Foundation Server and Team Explorer Plugin

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have to manage lots of changes every day in Visual Studio, and I've got a few tips for you, but no silver bullet:

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all items and then press a checkbox to toggle the checkboxes for all items.  This can be useful when performing changes to only a few items -- just uncheck everything, then make sure you have only the items checked that you'd like to update.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click (then right-click) to 'Undo' selected changes.  By default, the undo action will only apply to the selected items.

You might want to experiment with **using multiple Workspaces** -- and then filtering changes by workspace or by solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, ctrl-A makes the first issue much more bearable...I'll look into the multiple workspaces idea for the second

Comment: No problem.  Don't forget to vote up answers that you find helpful, or accept an answer if you feel it best solves your issue.  Cheers!

Comment: I just did....this is my first question so I didn't have enough reputation at the time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't know of a way to fix your problems.  It sounds like the best answer would be to refactor your configuration settings or code so that you can check in all of your changes.

Answer (score 0):

If your changes are in different projects you can partition what you check in using the Source Control Explorer by right clicking on the project folder and checking in that way. It will auto check only the files in the folder you right click on. Just keep in mind the Source Control Explorer gives you some other options. Otherwise, I do not know of a way to manually control your change sets file-by-file thought if this exists I would like to know about it too.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all items and then press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to toggle the checkedboxes as checked/unchecked.

Comment: -1 this answer does not improve upon the chosen answer's information, and it came 4 years later.